# How to distinguish between "the poor" and "poor people" in writing academic paper?

Tags: meaning

As a non-native English speaker, I am confused about the detailed meaning of the poor and poor people.

Similarly, what is difference between the homeless and homeless people?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you asking about the grammar or the connotations?  You really need to say what your research showed, and what was unclear after it.

Comment: 'Homeless' and 'poor' may be adjectives describing a person or a group of persons. Or they may be nouns describing the entire set of persons who are of that class. 'The poor' means all of the persons in society generally (or within a certain city, perhaps) who warrant that description.

Comment: They sound mostly the same to me. What is the motivation fro your question? Did a proofreader or teacher tell you to use one instead of the other?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you are writing an academic paper, then you should make it clear in the first place that you are talking about people who have a certain level of income or people who have no permanent homes due to a lack of financial resources.

After you define exactly what you mean in the context of your research, I would say "the homeless" or "the poor."

In terms of writing a paper more in the direction of philosophy or ethics, you might even choose to say "people of modest means" since the terms in your question above can be argued to be disempowering.

To conclude, there isn't really a difference in meaning apart from one way definitely points to human beings and the other implies human beings as the subject. The main difference is the connotation associated with the phrases. Whichever way you choose to say it, my advice would be to be clear and consistent throughout your paper.

Answer (score 0):

"the poor" is less appropriate than "poor people" for academic writing, but neither are particularly good, as they are vague and are often viewed as pejorative. Better is "low-income", and depending on the context, it likely is appropriate to define a particular income level and refer to this particular definition, rather than make general statements about "the poor".